# Bootstrap in a plugin conflicts with whole page Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I am writing a plugin for WordPress. It uses Bootstrap via link rel tag. Once I am done, I make a shortcode of the plugin and insert into the page I want. Then the wordpress bootstrap conflicts with the plugins' bootstrap.

Question: is it possible to somehow make them not conflict and keep my plugin style seperate from wordpress theme style?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can check if the current wordpress theme has bootstrap.css registered or enqueued and if it does don't add bootstrap rel link.

I've seen a solution to check for bootstrap in the theme [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104550/conditional-check-to-see-if-a-bootstrap-css-is-included-in-a-theme). Which can help get you started.